# Import SocialText wiki into MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

Does anyone have any experience converting a SocialText wiki into a MediaWiki? Is there any utility or script to perform the conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirements changed, now the client needs SocialText converted to Confluence Wiki. There is a Universal Wiki Converter that converts from most popular wiki formats to Confluence Wiki and they recently added SocialText to the list of supported wikis:

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFEXT/Universal+Wiki+Converter

Comment: This isn't quite an answer to the question though... Unless you also offer a way to export a Confluence wiki and convert the dump to MediaWiki format. If you do, please let us know at https://github.com/WikiTeam/wikiteam/issues/108